# Changing elements for spells

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

I think I remember in an older version of D&D allowing you to change a fire spell into a cold-based spell, or vice versa. In 5E, is there any way to allow you to alter say a Scorching Ray into a lightning or cold-based attack? I thought maybe sorcerer spell points might have done the trick, but I cannot find any rule that would cover it. 
I'm sure you could design and research a spell for that character during a downtime roleplaying option, but I was looking more for a 'on-the-fly' type option.

Comment: FYI, the feat ur talking about in 3.5 is [Energy Substitution](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Energy_Substitution)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is currently<sup>1</sup> no way to do this in the rules.

If you're trying to avoid damage resistance, there is a feat that can help you: Elemental Adept. It lets you choose an elemental damage type, and spells that deal damage of that type ignore resistance. So, for example, you could take Elemental Adept (Fire), and your *Scorching Ray*s would ignore fire resistance.

If you're trying to get around damage *immunity*, or exploit damage vulnerability, then you're out of luck. The only solution that currently exists is to pick spells with different damage types so that you always have the one you need.

Of course, this is D&D, so you could always ask your DM if they're willing to houserule something that would let you swap elements the way you want to. A metamagic option for the Sorcerer makes the most sense, but balancing it could be tricky. A Warlock invocation might also work here, but balancing it would be even harder.

<sup>1</sup> Current published materials: DMG, PHB, MM, Elemental Evil Player's Companion.

Comment: Definitely a consult your DM thing at present. The only reasoning behind such a change that Miniman hasn't mentioned is thematic: you want to play a storm-based caster, or a ice witch, or so on; in which case I would talk it out with my DM and ask for a lightning-variant of Scorching Ray with the understanding you'd never be using the fire-variant.

Comment: With regards to thematic mages, you have alot of options already. The elemental evil player's companion has made this a wide range of options. There are thematic cantrips which allow you to have power over an element (gust, control flames, mold earth and shape water), there is the first level spell, _chromatic orb_, which allows for most types of damage and not to mention good old fashion, changing the manifestation. Maybe  _scorching ray_ is lighting or ice so hot that it burns.

Answer (score 17):

With the introduction of Tasha's Cauldron of Everything, Sorcerers have gotten the new metamagic option Transmuted Spell that can do this. This is, as everything else in TCE, optional.

> When you cast a spell that deals a type of damage from the following list, you can spend 1 sorcery point to change that damage type to one of the other listed types: acid, cold, fire, lightning, poison, thunder.

Thanks to @Jon Aristotle in the comments, there is also another option from Tasha's, the Scribe Wizards Awakened Spellbook:

> When you cast a wizard spell with a spell slot, you can temporarily replace its damage type with a type that appears in another spell in your spellbook, which magically alters the spell's formula for this casting only. The latter spell must be of the same level as the spell slot you expend.

Comment: +1 I can just imagine it. Our Sorcerer casts *Fireball* but changes it to thunder-damage instead and pretty much obliterates the earth elementals that have been chasing us! Brilliant!

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any way to do in the official rules, however in [a new addition to the Unearthed Arcana](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/20170213_Wizrd_Wrlck_UAv2_i48nf.pdf), WoTC included the Wizard arcane tradition Lore Mastery that has a feature called Spell Secrets that can change the damage type of spells.

> **Spell Secrets:**  At 2nd level, you master the first in a series of
>   arcane secrets uncovered by your extensive studies.
>
> When you cast a spell with a spell slot and the spell deals acid, cold, fire, force, lightning, necrotic, radiant, or thunder damage, you can substitute that damage type with one other type from that list (you can change only one damage
>   type per casting of a spell). You replace one energy type for another by altering the spell’s formula as you cast it.
>
> When you cast a spell with a spell slot and the spell requires a saving throw, you can change the saving throw from one ability score to another of your choice. Once you change a saving throw in this way, you can’t do so again until you finish a short or long rest.

Given that this is in the UA and not currently in an official book, you should talk to your DM before using this arcane tradition.

It's also worthy of note that certain spells, such as chromatic orb, also allow you choose the damage type.

Comment: Note: the upcoming book, Xanathar's Guide to Everything, [will contain the UA subclasses that were deemed worth refining](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/872109482326839296). The Wizard had 2 UA subclasses, [but only 1 made the cut](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/871071659825872896) . I doubt Lore Master is the one; there was backlash over its abilities being too much like Sorcerer's, and Spell Secrets has some questionable interactions (e.g. changing Hold Person's save to Strength). A DM might take its failing to get into XGE as a sign that it's unfit for use.

Comment: @Doval this is true, except that the UA has introduced 3 arcane traditions (Theurgy, Lore Mastery, and War Magic) and I believe that Lore Master didn't make the cut either, partially because the Theurgy arcane tradition has had more time to be revised having been first introduced last year and was already revised once in the UA.  I see the reason for backlash given what you stated, though some subclasses do give classes features that have applications similar to others.  The questionable interactions with Spell Secrets is true, but that part could just be removed.  I agree with the last part.