# Is there any way for the Draconic Bloodline Sorcerer’s Elemental Affinity to improve Eldritch Blast, or is the Sage Advice Compendium just wrong?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, sorcerer, sage-advice

The Draconic Bloodline Sorcerer’s [elemental affinity](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#ElementalAffinity-378) ability says:

> Starting at 6th level, when you cast a spell that deals damage of the type associated with your draconic ancestry, you can add your Charisma modifier to one damage roll of that spell.

The cantrip [*eldritch blast*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/eldritch-blast) deals force damage, and force damage does not appear on the Draconic ancestry table.

Nevertheless, the [*Sage Advice Compendium*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium) ruling on elemental affinity states:

> Elemental Affinity benefits one damage roll per casting of a spell, even if the spell allows more than one roll. So, for example, the feature improves one of the rays of a scorching ray spell or *one of the beams of an eldritch blast spell*.

Is this just a case of using *eldritch blast* as a contextually incorrect choice of category representative of the type of spells this Sage Advice ruling is addressing, or is there a way to modify the damage type of *eldritch blast* so that it is an actual use case for this ruling on the elemental affinity ability?

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58672/43856

Comment: Almost a duplicate: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147971/43856

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This sounds like a mix of example of multi-hit spells and some potential future proofing because subclasses like the [Loremaster Wizard from UA](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/20170213_Wizrd_Wrlck_UAv2_i48nf.pdf) may eventually exist officially which allow you to change the elemental type of damage cantrips.

For example,

> Taken from *Spell Secrets*
> When you cast a spell with a spell slot and the spell deals acid, cold, fire, **force**, lightning, necrotic, radiant, or thunder damage, **you can substitute that damage type with one other type from that list** (you can change only one damage type per casting of a spell). You replace one energy type for another by altering the spell's formula as you cast it.

This ability does not work on Eldritch Blast as is, but in the future *an ability like it* might.

At the very least, using Eldritch Blast as an example demonstrates the kind of spell that, *were it elemental*, would qualify for only adding the damage to one roll.

Comment: Welp, got ninja'd. But why do you say it doesn't work on Eldritch Blast?

Comment: @HellSaint Spell slot requirement. "**When you cast a spell with a spell slot**"

Comment: Oh, I didn't even realize there was a spell slot requirement. Lol.

Comment: So is sage compendium wrong?

Comment: @GcL In their surgically-culled statement: "Elemental Affinity benefits one damage roll per casting of a spell, ... So, for example, the feature improves... one of the beams of an eldritch blast spell." They are **wrong** that Elemental Affinity improves *any* of the beams of eldritch blast *unless there is a feature which gives it one of the above elements*. As of right now, there is no officially released content that will make them **right**, ***yet***.

Comment: @Axoren I like that answer to the question.

Comment: @GcL Tasha's Cauldron of Everything released 4 months after this question and answer. On page 66,
"Transmuted Spell Metamagic: When you cast a spell dealing damage from the following list, you can spend 1 sorcery point to change that damage type to one of the other listed types: acid, cold, fire, lightning, poison, thunder"
It has no mention of "spell **using a spell slot**" so you could change damage cantrips' elemental damage, but force is not one listed.